# Managed Package, Security Review and LWC DOM Manipulation

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, security-review, third-party

I started developing a managed package and I need to manipulate the DOM in a Lightning Web Component, In the component HTML, I added lwc:dom="manual" to the target element and everything works well.

When I run it through Clayton it gives me an issue regarding XSS:

> This component uses direct DOM manipulation, which is not recommended
> as it increases the risk of XSS.

Does anyone have an idea if that could be an issue once I request the security review?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is Clayton? Can you provide us with a link? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning should not automatically fail your security review. However, your package will need additional analysis to determine if there is any actual XSS vectors. As long as you're following best practices, your package could still pass security review. You should direct specific questions to [Partner Support](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/support).

Comment: THanks for your answer!